# FastAPI behind CloudFlare, real client ip problem

Tags: python, kubernetes, fastapi

I have the following simple FastAPI micro-service:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI(docs_url=None, redoc_url=None, title="Get Forecast")

@app.get(path="/get_weather")
def get_weather(request: Request)

  ..some logic behind the scene...

  return response.json()
```

External client's requests go in the following way:

`External User -> CloudFlare -> K8S Ingress Nginx Controller -> Micro-service`

The task is to configure FastAPI to get real client's ip for the logging purpose.

@app starts in the following way:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(
        "main:app",
        host="0.0.0.0",
        port=8443,
        reload=True,
        ssl_keyfile="./ssl/key.pem",
        ssl_certfile="./ssl/cert.pem",
        server_header=False,
        proxy_headers=True,
        forwarded_allow_ips="*",
    )
```

All headers were proxied and thats fine, but FastAPI gets the real ip from the header "X-Real-IP"/"X-Forwarded-For", which is CloudFlare's ip address.

request headers if i print them in the micro-service:

```
Headers({'host': 'api-dev.test-123.com', 'x-request-id': 'xxxx', 
'x-real-ip': '162.158.x.x','x-forwarded-for': '162.158.x.x', 'x-forwarded-host': 'api-dev.test-123.com', 
'x-forwarded-port': '443', 'x-forwarded-proto': 'https', 'x-forwarded-scheme': 'https', 'x-scheme': 'https', 
'x-original-forwarded-for': '185.x.x.x', 'cf-connecting-ip': '185.x.x.x', 'cf-ipcountry': 'US', 
'accept-encoding': 'gzip', 'cf-ray': 'xxx', 'cf-visitor': {"scheme":"https"}, 'user-agent': 'curl/1.1', 
'accept': '*/*', 'x-access-key': 'test-key', 'cdn-loop': 'cloudflare'})
```

I need to log real (Not CloudFlare's) client ip and get it from the header: "CF-Connecting-IP"/"X-Original-Forwarded-For", because every time i have in logs cloudflare's  ip address:

`INFO:     162.158.x.x:0 - "GET /get_weather HTTP/1.1" 200 OK`

What is the good solution for doing that?
I've tried to do the following, but i'm not able to change `request.client.host` param bcs its named tuple.

```py
custom_header_name = "X-Original-Forwarded-For"

@app.middleware("http")
async def set_client_ip(request: Request, call_next):
    client_ip = request.headers.get(custom_header_name)
    if client_ip:
        request.client.host = client_ip
    response = await call_next(request)
    return response
```

I've also tried to rewrite X-Real-IP on the Ingress controller but without any luck.
Any ideas for solving this?

Comment: Every cloudflare will include its own headers in the request. Try to look for a `CF-Connecting-IP` header, that is the IP address of the original sender of the request.

Comment: yep, i've already tried to catch "CF-Connecting-IP" or "X-Original-Forwarded-For", but in FastAPI logs still CloudFlare's ip address from X-Real-IP header

Comment: The logger will only log the cloudflare IP as that is what it reads in the header. If you want to log with the request user IP address, you will unfortunately have to set up custom `logging` for your API. This is really easy to do, however it is not the a solution to the primary problem, rather it is a work-around so I think that the best course of action in your case is to delete this question and refer to `ChatGPT`, I just asked and it gave me a solution.

Comment: the last one code part its `ChatGPT` suggestion which is doesnt work. Thats not a problem to setup custom `logger`, but this will not solve a problem. Btw, how to tell `FastAPI` to take ip address from the another header and show in logs? Is it possible in some way?

Comment: Generally it's uvicorn logging the request, not FastAPI - so I don't think changing anything directly in FastAPI will hange what uvicorn uses. However, the suggested solution seems to be to make a small logging middleware and then use that, since as far as I can tell uvicorn doesn't support reffering to a given http header in its log format: https://github.com/encode/uvicorn/issues/773 - The linked repo can be used as a template: https://github.com/Kludex/asgi-logger

Comment: @MatsLindh It depends on the serve which serves the FastAPI. Could be `uvicorn` as you suggested or it could be `uWSGI` or `phusion passenger` or any range of servers. However, you can create a separate logger within the `FastAPI` itself.

Comment: @Dimitar OP included the code which starts the server using uvicorn; in any case, a ASGI middleware is probably the way to go in either case.